# How to have div to be vertically on the right side of my left div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to use various paddings and margins to move the div beneath the dotted div. I would like the div that is at the bottom right now to be vertically on the right side of the other div, as shown in this [link](https://app.sketchtogether.com/s/sketch/BHh7T.5.1/) Can someone give some direction on what should I look into or do, maybe I am approaching padding and margins incorrectly?

```css
 #div {
        border-style: dotted;
        width: 70%;
    }
```

```html
<head>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid bg-white py-4">
        <div class="container">

            <div id="div">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit vero doloribus perferendis alias
                dolor possimus eum pariatur adipisci ipsa id deserunt, iste veritatis architecto ratione esse,
                molestiae dolore quibusdam porro! Lorem, ipsum dolor.
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi laboriosam in quam? Tempora
                dolorum incidunt accusantium veritatis repellat corporis quas alias, quasi exercitationem molestias,
                libero quibusdam cumque voluptatibus, hic labore?
            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus deserunt aliquam nisi voluptatum
            exercitationem repudiandae illo dolores aut, dolorem ipsam fugiat perferendis tempora quaerat deleniti
            voluptates corporis temporibus nemo dolore.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bootstrap then you can just divide them into two columns, just like below code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
      <p>DIV 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>DIV 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```